# Can heterocyclic molecules form sandwich-like complexes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

As unsaturated heterocycles have the same planar structure as cyclopentadiene ion/benzene "sandwich" compounds, I was wondering if a similar coordination between metals can be achieved.

When asking this question, it is related to the potential geometry formed that is similar to that of sandwich compounds, not similar bonding characteristics. That is, a ion above the centre of molecule, not adjacent to the side.
If there is any literature on this topic, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, heterocyclic compounds are viable for the $\pi$-donation necessary to coordinate a metal as a sandwich complex—the electron distribution about the $\pi$-system is different, so bonding characteristics aren't guaranteed to fully translate (you may get for a five-membered ring an $\eta^4$ coordination instead of an $\eta^5$ coordination sometimes, for example). If a heteroatom has substantial p-character in its electron density, then in theory it can participate in the binding to the metal.

[Here is a link to a related 1993 review on the subject](https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-8545(93)85037-5) if you can find a way around the paywall.